# Find the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^{1/k}}{k}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Numerically, I think the answer converges to 2, but I couldn't come up with a function that it converges to pointwise. Also I couldn't think of a dominating function to apply to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, at least not in one dimension. I also tried using a Lebesgue integral approach but couldn't simplify that series either (letting $S_n$ be the partial sum in the title):

\begin{align}
S_n &= \frac{1}{n}\cdot (n - n^{1/2}) + \frac{2}{n}\cdot (n^{1/2} - n^{1/3}) + \ldots + \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot (n^{1/(n-2)} - n^{1/(n-1)}) + n^{1/n}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left\{ \frac{k}{n}(n^{1/k} - n^{1/(k+1)})\right\} + n^{1/n}.
\end{align}

Comment: Based on trying various values for $n$ the sum seems to be very, very close to $n$ for $n$ sufficiently large. For example, $n=10^{10}$ is just slightly over. [Wolfram for reference.](https://is.gd/A8zcUD) So are you *sure* it converges to $2$? It seems awfully divergent to me.

Comment: Your manipulations of $S_n$ all have $n$ in the denominator, but the sum in the title has $k$.  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If $n>2$ then $\frac {n^{1/k}} k >\frac {2^{1/k}} k$. The series $\sum \frac {2^{1/k}} k$ is divergent. What conclusion can you draw from this?

Answer (score 1):

$n^{1/k} \ge 1$, $n,k \ge 1$.

$\dfrac{1}{k} \le \dfrac{n^{1/k}}{k}.$

$\sum \dfrac{1}{k}$, the harmonic series , diverges .

By comparison test $\sum \dfrac{n^{1/k}}{k}$ diverges.